# How to get output from Fiona instead of fiona.model object

Tags: python, shapefile, fiona

I'm following the examples in [the docs](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#records) but using Virginia's [parcel shp file](https://gismaps.vdem.virginia.gov/download/BaseMapData/SHP/VirginiaParcel.shp.zip). Warning: it's about 1GB zipped and 1.8GB unzipped.

I have very simply

```
fiava = fiona.open("VirginiaParcel.shp/VirginiaParcel.shp", layer='VirginiaParcel')
```

from which I can do `fiava.schema` to get

```
# {'properties': {'FIPS': 'str:8',
#   'LOCALITY': 'str:64',
#   'PARCELID': 'str:64',
#   'PTM_ID': 'str:64',
#   'LASTUPDATE': 'date',
#   'VGIN_QPID': 'str:50'},
#  'geometry': 'Polygon'}
```

So far so good

but when I do

```
fiava[0]
## I get a Feature object, not the data
## <fiona.model.Feature at 0x7f2fd582aa10>
```

In the docs it shows this output

```
{'geometry': {'coordinates': [[(-4.663611, 51.158333),
                            (-4.669168, 51.159439),
                            (-4.673334, 51.161385),
                            (-4.674445, 51.165276),
                            (-4.67139, 51.185272),
                            (-4.669445, 51.193054),
                            (-4.665556, 51.195),
                            (-4.65889, 51.195),
                            (-4.656389, 51.192215),
                            (-4.646389, 51.164444),
                            (-4.646945, 51.160828),
                            (-4.651668, 51.159439),
                            (-4.663611, 51.158333)]],
            'type': 'Polygon'},
'id': '1',
'properties': OrderedDict([('CAT', 232.0), ('FIPS_CNTRY', 'UK'), ('CNTRY_NAME', 'United Kingdom'), ('AREA', 244820.0), ('POP_CNTRY', 60270708.0)]),
'type': 'Feature'}
```

If I use the schema for the specific keys then I can get data one value at a time but this is not optimal

```
fiava[0]['properties']['FIPS']
## 51149
```

Even if I do `fiava[0].items()` then it's just an `ItemsView`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fiona.model.to_dict()`

```
from fiona.model import to_dict
d = to_dict(fiava[0])
```

if you want to serialize the data as json without calling `to_dict()` on each object, you can use the `fiona.model.ObjectEncoder`:

```
import json
from fiona.model import ObjectEncoder

j = json.dumps(fiava, cls=ObjectEncoder)
```